# Specific instance of a vector of objects into a array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, object, vector

I am trying to convert a specific instance of my object vector into an array of strings.  The object vector contains ints, doubles and string, but I only want to get one string instance of the vector to turn it into an array and I am running into issues.  This is one of the things I've tried.

```
 String [] tempNameA = new String [dogParkProgramMain.infoVector.size()];

    for(int x1 = 0; x1<dogParkProgramMain.infoVector.size(); x1++)
 {
        tempNameA[x1] = dogParkProgramMain.infoVector.elementAt(x1).getFName().get(x1).toString();
 }
```

Comment: Looks like it should work, assuming `getFName()` returns another `String[]`. Post the relevant class structures and the stacktrace.

Comment: How can your vector contain 2 types of primitives and `String`? Do you mean `Integer` and `Double` instead of `int` and `double`?